# Change materialSwitch colors in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets

How can I change the colors of a `materialSwitch` element in a Shiny app?
I know that `tags$style(...)` can be used inside ui.R to modify CSS styles, but I don’t know the specific class names of these kind of elements.

Comment: The CSS file is available [here](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets/blob/master/inst/assets/material-switch/material-switch.css). Does it help? You should also try to inspect the HTML elements when you're looking for a class name (in Chrome: right-click on the element, then "Inspect").

Comment: Thanks for the head-up, but no, I wasn’t able to change the color of the material-switch knob. I tried with ```tags$style(type = "text/css", ".material-switch > label::before {background: #1D60A4; !important}”)``` and many variations of ```.material-switch``` and ```label``` but I only got as far as changing text background color, which is not what I intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out how to change the color of an active MaterialSwitch button. Just add the following to your Shiny app on your ui.R file:

```
tags$style(type = "text/css", "
  .label-default {background-color: #1574D6;}
  "),
```

In this example, the switch turns to color blue when active.

Comment: To change colors for inactive switches you can use `  tags$style("
             .switch label .lever {
             background-color:rgba(44, 161, 245, .5);
             }
             .switch label .lever:after {
             background-color:rgba(44, 161, 245, .9);
             }
             "),`